# parsing json android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have one question. I need to parse JSON on Android, but I have several URIs and some of them have parameters. How can I send a request to the server? When I specify only URI without the parameters, I receive the message:

> "{"code":200,"error":"An unforeseen
>   error has happened. Appeal to the
>   developers."}"

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve here - please add more explanations and e.g. code snippets.

Comment: Heiko Rupp - I have
{ "cities" : [ { "id(int)" : 1,
"name(string)" : "London"
},
{ "id(int)" : 2,
"name(string)" : "Paris"
}   and I need get providers. but for receiving provider i should specify Parameters:
● cityId(int) how should i do this?

Answer (score 1):

As you said

> Appeal to the developers.

who wrote the service.